# How to select only unique values in a form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a form that I would like to show only unique values for the first `options _for_select`. What would I need to change for the following form to have that result?

```
<%= form_for @domain, :url => {:controller => "page_scraper", :action => "compare"} do |f| %>
  <%=select_tag 'domain', options_for_select(@savedHTML.collect{ |u| [u.domain, u.domain] })%> 
  <%=select_tag 'version_one', options_for_select(@savedHTML.collect{ |u| [u.created_at, u.created_at] })%>
  <%=select_tag 'version_two', options_for_select(@savedHTML.collect{ |u| [u.created_at, u.created_at] })%>
  <%=f.submit "Compare" %>
<% end %>
```

controller

```
def index       
    @savedHTML = ScrapedPage.all

end
```

Comment: Did you try this ?  @savedHTML.uniq.collect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `.uniq` method on a collection to remove duplicates.

```
<%= form_for @domain, :url => {:controller => "page_scraper", :action => "compare"} do |f| %>
  <%=select_tag 'domain', options_for_select(@savedHTML.collect{ |u| [u.domain, u.domain] }.uniq)%> 
  <%=select_tag 'version_one', options_for_select(@savedHTML.collect{ |u| [u.created_at, u.created_at] })%>
  <%=select_tag 'version_two', options_for_select(@savedHTML.collect{ |u| [u.created_at, u.created_at] })%>
  <%=f.submit "Compare" %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: If u sed `.uniq` before `.collection` it would not work, only if I did it like you put it in your example. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can try below code. When you perform uniq on collection at that time it will give you uniq records then after you can perform any operation on each.

```
<%= form_for @domain, :url => {:controller => "page_scraper", :action => "compare"} do |f| %>
  <%= select_tag 'domain', options_for_select(@savedHTML.uniq.collect{ |u| [u.domain, u.domain] })%> 
  <%= select_tag 'version_one', options_for_select(@savedHTML.collect{ |u| [u.created_at, u.created_at] })%>
  <%= select_tag 'version_two', options_for_select(@savedHTML.collect{ |u| [u.created_at, u.created_at] })%>
  <%= f.submit "Compare" %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: I have tried both `.uniq` and `.distinct` in my view and controller and I have all values in my droptdown and I do not understand why.

Answer (score 0):

Update in controller

controller

```
def index       
  @savedHTML = ScrapedPage.all.uniq
end
```

Answer (score 0):

In Rails 5.1 You can use `distinct` to get the unique values from controller and then can perform operations in view

**Controller**

```
def index
 @savedHTML = ScrapedPage.all.distinct
end
```

**View**

```
<%= form_for @domain, :url => {:controller => "page_scraper", :action => "compare"} do |f| %>
  <%=select_tag 'domain', options_for_select(@savedHTML.collect{ |u| [u.domain, u.domain] })%> 
  <%=select_tag 'version_one', options_for_select(@savedHTML.collect{ |u| [u.created_at, u.created_at] })%>
  <%=select_tag 'version_two', options_for_select(@savedHTML.collect{ |u| [u.created_at, u.created_at] })%>
  <%=f.submit "Compare" %>
<% end %>
```